# How do I get my entire image into a header?

Tags: html, css, image

Here is the current code I am using, and I want the entire image to appear:

```
.main #header {
height: 240px;
border-bottom: 1px solid #EEE;
background: url("Irie Photo.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed; 
 -webkit-background-size: cover;
 -moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
```

Here is the HTML calling the class:

```
<div id="header">
            <div class="fb-like" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/theiriecollection" data-width="50" data-layout="standard" 
                 data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true" style="float: right;"></div>
            <h1>Welcome to the Irie Collection!</h1>


        </div>
```

Comment: Can you clarify? What do you mean by "exactly how it looks"? What is wrong with the image currently?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Try to add `<img src="photo.png"/>` inside of header. Try to describe your question better, thanks.

Comment: I just want my entire image to appear in the header.  Right now only part of it does.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```

to make the image appear in original state stretched to height, with the comment you posted I think you want to use the above one

```
background-size: auto 100%;
```

to make the image appear in original state stretch to width

```
background-size: (image-height here) (image-width here)
```

to make the image in the original state (replace the letters to the pixels of the image)

If none of them is the one your looking for, please specify your code

Answer (score 0):

I don`t really understand your question, but maybe you are searching for:

```
{background-size: contain}
```

Comment: I ended up just downloading GIMP and resizing the image